# Make Bootstrap columns appear in one row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used Bootstrap before, but I'm having an issue with columns. I cannot find an answer on stackoverflow.

My columns are appearing in two rows instead of one.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n0syj75t/

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="header row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-63-7.jpg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8 header-menu">
        <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
            <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="#">Services</a></li>

                <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="#">How We Work</a></li>

                <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>

                <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>

</div><!-- end header row -->
</div><!-- end container-fluid -->
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    height: 110px;
}

.header ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 0;
}

.header li, .header-menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.header-menu a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 45px;
    color: #7f7f7f;
}

/* Bootstrap rows and columns --------------------------------------- */

.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-sm-1 { 
    width: 8.33333333%; 
}

.col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9 { 
     float: left;
}

.col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}

.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: are you try to create navbar or just column?

Comment: I already check your coding seem working perfectly. http://www.bootply.com/tZLZy7Iphi you may check this link. Can you explain more what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to get all 3 columns to align in one row, just like that bootply you showed me. It looks like the problem is in some code in my website that I didn't copy and paste here. I'm looking into it and will update my question once I find the code I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Because your image and menu are exceeding 100% of width, please add inside each `max-width:100%`. Also, you did not load the full bootstrap, you lack the `*{margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box}`

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n0syj75t/1/

I've added this, please change it either to the bootstrap class `.img-responsive` or add your own class

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
}

.header-menu a {
    padding:25px; //The original is too big, will be pushed to a new row
}
```

Also, when the window's width is less than the **small size**, your columns will expand into rows for mobile viewing as said in the bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I do know about the columns collapsing into two rows with mobile. I'm referencing https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css in my code. That seems to fix it in the fiddle, but not on my website. Something else might be going on. I'll investigate and see what the code is on my website that isn't in my question.

Comment: @Tara sorry, i've also altered your `padding:45px`, that's too big and will have be pushed to a second row

Comment: I just noticed that col-sm-4 in the banner is left aligned when it should be closer to the center.

Comment: Wow, firstly, you shouldn't use `.container-fluid` here and take out all the `.row`s

Comment: Aren't columns supposed to be nested in rows? Also, I used container-fluid to make my rows full width. What is an alternative to doing that?

Comment: @Tara here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/n0syj75t/3/ please notice i've made changes to html and css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87097/discussion-between-tara-and-daniel-cheung).